# Call Function from Storyboard ViewController?

Tags: ios, ios4, storyboard

I have my project setup as a storyboard.

There is a subview, I have opened that view and I would like to access the storyboard `UIViewController's` functions to trigger an event.

Is something like this possible to access?

Comment: Can you be more detailed in what you want to achieve? Including some code would be useful too :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you're not triggering the transition through storyboard, you're normally better using the old fashioned way.

```
UIViewController* newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
// do whatever setup you want here


[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC];
```

When the stuff you're doing fits with the storyboard method, it is great, but it doesn't give you anything you can't do by hand, and once you start passing anything complicated between VCs, the advantage saved by not having to implement IBActions is quickly offset by having to write complicated prepareForSeque and the like.